# Implicit Auth Grant

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am working on some project in spring boot in which Oauth 2.0 is implemented which have grant type as password. I want to change it to "implicit" auth grant. But I have read in one of the article that, it is not safe to use this strategy, as it use token along with URL.

So should I change it to "implicit" or look for any other grant type.
This is the link of above mentioned article.

https://medium.com/oauth-2/why-you-should-stop-using-the-oauth-implicit-grant-2436ced1c926

Answer (score 0):

You should not use implicit grant type as it is also not recommended by OAUTH.

[Please refer draft link of security best practices provided by OAuth which shows problems with implicit.](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-13#section-3.1.2)